# MacOS mechanism for customized URL scheme

Tags: xcode, macos, url-scheme

I am trying to understand how customized URL scheme works in Mac, as explained here : https://css-tricks.com/create-url-scheme/

For example, when a mailto:link is clicked, a user sees the ‘Mail’ application starts and it pops up a composer window with proper receiver address already filled out.

I am pretty sure in Windows, you can pass the string related to your protocol (e.g. including receiver's address etc.) as a command line argument when invoking the handling application. That is, you get a chance to parse the command line as your handling app launches.

But it seems this is not the case in MacOS? In the above example, does it invokes 'Mail' first, then 'Mail' gets the string related to the protocol (receiver’s address etc.) from its registered callback? i.e. you can only get the address when the handling application **already started running**?

In Mac, is it possible to do the same thing as in Windows, passing command line arguments when launching the handling application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the above example, does it invokes 'Mail' first, then 'Mail' gets the string related to the protocol (receiver’s address etc.) from its registered callback? i.e. you can only get the address when the handling application already started running?

Correct. Once the application has launched -- if it was not already running -- it receives an event (via [Apple Events](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applicationservices/apple_event_manager)!) informing it that it should open the URL.

> In Mac, is it possible to do the same thing as in Windows, passing command line arguments when launching the handling application?

No. As a rule, macOS applications generally do not use command line arguments. In this specific case, command line arguments would be unsuitable anyway, as they cannot be used to pass information to an application which is already open.

Comment: and that event should be already delivered (handler called) before it calls "applicationDidFinishLaunching", right?